# How to find column existence in data table in C#?

Tags: c#

I have problem. I have 2 queries in a stored procedure. Both run on certain condition if condition is true query one executes and returns 7 columns from 3 tables. If condition fail 2nd query returns 4 columns.

On front end I use a datatable to store query result. I assign values to textbox from datatable.

like

dt is data table name

```
Txt_name.Text=dt.Rows[0][6].ToString();
```

problem is that when 2nd query executes an error occurs. No columns exists at 6.

How I find dt has column at at index 6 or not?

Comment: Using ordinals is very poor form. Named columns are far more scaleable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
 int indx = 6;
 if(dt != null and dt.Columns.Count > indx)
 {
     Txt_name.Text=dt.Rows[0][indx].ToString();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the colums count something like below:

```
int index = 6;
Txt_name.Text = dt.Columns.Count > index ? dt.Rows[0][index].ToString() : String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to modify the stored procedure? And also manage all resources that use this stored procedure? I would recommend that it return the same structure regardless of the result.

If there is a false result, just have the additional fields empty. You can achieve this with the `COALESCE` operator, which return a given value (as `''` in case of empty string) if there is NULL (i.e. no records in joined table).

> A function that behave different base on a fields-count will nearly
>   works as a Insurance to break the code in future. There will be a
>   magic number "6" which can make behavior of the if-else-clause invert
>   or always evaluate same result. If the stored procedure HAVE to return
>   different structures, evaluate true/false first an then call the
>   adequate stored procedure.